# Android SoftKeyboard how to create own suggestions

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, autosuggest

I am developing a keyboard based on the softkeyboard sample. I would like to know how do I create my own suggestions. I see the setSuggestion method in Candidate View Class but in the parameter of that method, I see a list of string(Suggestions) is passed into the this method. My question is do I have to create my own algorithm for the suggestions in the setSuggestion method or another method from which the string array is passed.

Comment: did you find any solution?